# VS Code Formatting failed (.clang-format:49:1: error: unknown key 'CustomTernaryOps')

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am running VS Code on Ubuntu 20.04 and code formatting doesn't seems to work for C/C++ although I have the necessary extensions installed. When I press "Ctrl+Alt+I" it says `Formatting failed. See the output window for details.`

Here is what the output window says.

```
Formatting failed:
/home/fmu/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.7.1/bin/../LLVM/bin/clang-format -style=file -fallback-style=LLVM -assume-filename=/home/fmu/temp/coqoshv/src/core/vcpu-mgr/_new.c
/home/fmu/temp/coqoshv/src/core/.clang-format:49:1: error: unknown key 'CustomTernaryOps'
  CustomTernaryOps: true # custom option for not breaking lines on ternary ops when possible
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Error reading /home/fmu/temp/coqoshv/src/core/.clang-format: Invalid argument
```

Can somebody help me on what could be the problem here. Thanks.

Comment: Code that, when attempted to format, produces this condition, would make for a *considerable* addition to the quality of your question. [Please add it.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70971504/edit)

Comment: `CustomTernaryOps` doesn't seem to be a valid clangformat setting, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: As @AlanBirtles pointed out `CustomTernaryOps` seems to be not valid, in https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html you can see the options. Check `BreakBeforeTernaryOperators` option, seems to be related.

Answer (score 0):

Check-in `[llvm.org][1]` which version of the formatter the option requires.

You can then manually run the formatter to see what version it is.

I had an issue where it didn't even post a message in the output window.

But by manually running the formatter located there: `~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.9.8-linux-x64/LLVM/bin/clang-format`, I got messages pointing out that I had an options which was only usable for a greater version than the formatter supported.